# Check the functions before submit in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello there,**

When I submit the form without writing any things in fields the form submitted without check my validation function, that's my code in JQ and I declare the variables in global to check out in the function submit, what's wrong in these?

```
$(function() {
    $('.names').hide();
    $('.username').hide();
    $('.email').hide();
    $('.password').hide();
    $('.co-password').hide();

    var error_user = false;
    var error_username = false;
    var error_pass = false;
    var error_email = false;

  $('#registerForm').submit(function(){
        error_user = false;
        error_username = false;
        error_pass = false;
        error_email = false;

        check_user();
        check_username();
        check_email();
        check_pass();
        confirm_password();

        if(error_user === false && error_username === false &&
            error_email === false && error_pass === false ){
            alert('Successfully !');
            $('#submitPass').html('Rigesteration Sucessfull!').css('color','green');
            return true;
        }else{
            alert('Please fill the form !');
            $('#submitPass').html('Please fill the form !').css('color','red');
            return false;
        }
    });
   });
```

**some example about one function:**

```
    function check_user(){
        var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
        var fname = $('#name').val();
        if(fname.length <= 0){
            $('.names').show();
            $('#Ename').html('please enter your name');
            $('#name').css('border-color','#f14343');
        }
        else{
            if(pattern.test(fname) && fname !== ''){
                $('.names').hide();
                $('#name').css('border-color','#29f44b');
            }else{
                $('#Ename').html('The Name Shouldn\'t Contain Bad Char ');
                $('.names').show();
                $('#name').css('border-color','#f14343');
                error_user = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `error_user` variable is not global, so `error_user = false;` in your submit function is different variable than `error_user = true;` in your `check_user` function.

Comment: no, it's global but I don't insert them in the code

Comment: @max look the edited.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Is `check_user()` declared inside the same `$(function()` ? Would be better to have those functions return the error state and not rely on those external variables. Then would be more like `var error_user = check_user()`

Comment: @charlietfl is right, if your `check_user` function is outside `$(function() {` these are different variables because `$(function() {` creates a new scope.

Comment: @max yes I'm declared all the validation function inside the same $(function(){}), the problem when I submit the form without writing anything in the inputs there are submitted without check function submit

Comment: You set `error_user = true;` only in second `else`. What about `error_user = true;` if length is `<= 0`?

Comment: @Yes I had to define it in the first statement

Comment: the same wrong is still :/

Comment: @charlietfl can you show me what you want in editing my code

Comment: @max Thank you I have defined the variables in the first If Statment the problem has been resolved, but I have some Question, i declare some var inside the function how to make them to global?

Comment: Simplified example http://jsfiddle.net/y94xzfeo/

Comment: @charlietfl thank you man